# Resized Ubuntu Partition on Windows, can't get past grub rescue

Tags: boot, dual-boot, grub2, boot-partition

I know this has been asked many times before but I cannot seem to find an answer that is helping me get past this.
When I enter grub rescue and use the ls command I tried to use view each partition but none of them seemed to contain Ubuntu.

I then tried to boot from a USB but if i try to install or try to use Ubuntu from the stick is just ends up in a black screen.

The last thing I tried to do was unplug the SSD where i installed Ubuntu but I still got the grub recovery message.

I'm at a complete loss for what to do any help would be very appreciated.  I don't have access to my windows live install disc.
I'm using Windows 10
Ubuntu 16.04
Grub 2.02

Hardware: Samsung 840 Evo, Western digital black and blue
Gtx 970 4g msi
Asus Z710-a 
8GB'S of RAM
A wifi network card, something from TP-Link

Not sure if I am missing anything relevant

On a side note I would be willing to do a complete wipe of my C drive if it is even possible from bios

I think I found the answer, the screen would say no signal dedicated so that what was causing all the issues.  I'm just going to do a fresh install and hope that ends this nightmare.  I will update this as solved once everything is fixed.

Update:
Looks like I'm an idiot and it was a simple fix.  I just added nomodeset between splash and screen in the grub command line and that let me re install from a USB. For some reason my bios doesn't detect my ssd in boot priority but i can force boot it.  I'll deal with that at a later date as I think it still uses the ssd afterwards since it's a fast startup but whatever.
Thanks for the help everyone.

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu! Please [edit](http://askubuntu.com/posts/885652/edit) your question and add more details on what hardware you try to install Ubuntu.

Comment: Have you tried [Boot-Repair](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair)? Please add the URL from Boot-Repair into your question.

Comment: Unfortunately I don't have access to another computer at the moment, but i will latter on today so I will give that a go

Answer (score 0):

I've run into the blank screen issue a few times with live usb disks and you can get through by pressing Enter after a bit of time. You will then see the usb key light starting to shine and your computer will boot. If Enter does not work, just press other keys until you see that the key comes alive.

Comment: Is there a specific time frame to press enter or should l just mash the key?

Comment: I just wait a bit and then hit it, multiple times :) I'm not the waiting kind.

Answer (score 0):

I've been through one of these errors. The best way to fix this problem is booting either from an Ubuntu live-session (boot your computer on a Ubuntu live-CD or live-USB then choose "Try Ubuntu") or from your installed Ubuntu session (if you can access it)

- connect to the Internet
- open a new Terminal, then type the following commands (press Enter after each line):

sudo add-apt-repository ppa:yannubuntu/boot-repair
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install -y boot-repair && boot-repair

This is a demo that helps in every trouble in facing a dual boot error or grub error.
Hope this helps!!

Answer (score 0):

Looks like I'm an idiot and it was a simple fix.  I just added nomodeset between splash and screen in the grub command line.  I was able to get a signal to my monitor and that let me re install from a USB.
For some reason my bios doesn't detect my ssd in boot priority but i can force boot it.  I'll deal with that at a later date as I think it still uses the ssd afterwards since it's a fast startup but whatever.
I also have no clue why i can boot from my HDD but whatever, I count this problem as solved.